# laravel additional parameter for report helper function

Tags: laravel

I want to supply an additional parameter to laravels report helper function so I can call it this way:

```
report($exception, 'Some additional info');
```

I have therefore changed the app/Exceptions/Handler class:

```
public function report(Exception $exception, string $message = null)
{
    if($message) {
        SendErrorMails::raw($message, $exception->getMessage());
    }
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

However the IDE still complains that it only takes 1 parameter.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson PhpStorm

Comment: Have you added a new helper function as well? If not, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: no I have not changed anything with the report function. I assumed it would just map to the report method in the Handler class

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is nothing magical about how Laravel defines its global helper functions. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.5

Comment: https://github.com/funkjedi/composer-include-files

Answer (score 1):

The `report` helper is *not* the `report` method of the exception handler.

You must create your own helper like so

```
function customReport(Exception $exception, string $message = null) {
    // Call the exception handler report method here
}
```

See the `report` helper code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L668) for more info.